# How to avoid updating a new column in table using hibernate when a custom column is added in the query?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

How to avoid updating a new column in table using hibernate when a custom column is added in the query?
I'm writing a query to retrive a column from a DB function which is making the table updated with the new column added.

Query:

```
SELECT distinct dm.m_id , CONCAT(dm.m_name, ',', dm.name) as m_name,
             fm.actual, **get_user_color_status(dm.m_id,0) as colrStatus**
            FROM public.d_metric dm
```

The higlighted column is getting updated in the table.
**In application.properties:**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Removing the above is causing my framework running unsucessfully.
Please let me know how to avoid this situation .

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you show the hibernate code that produced the query ? How is the new column mapped in the entity ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. calling a function inside my query as mentioned above get_user_color_status(dm.m_id,0) as colrStatus. And having thecolrStatus object in my DTO class where I'm writing code in serviceImpl as      String colorStatus = userObj.setStatus();
            userCodeValue.setStatus(colorStatus);
            }*/

Comment: Since 'colrStatus' column is not there in the existing table which is getting updated with the above hibernate property mentioned in app.prop

Answer (score 0):

Created a model class and not extending to JPA repository solved the issue